# Java Kafka Customize Producer Error Logging Format

Tags: java, spring, logging, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have problem on logging from the kafka error. I am currently integrate our logging to alert program using OpsGenie and our logging is recorded in Loki
We want to make our log with same data to be grouped in one log only, the OpsGenie that creating the alert is already have mechanism to group the alert by log `message`

The problem is in error that logged by kafka error. The `org.springframework.kafka.support.LoggingProducerListener` have logged each message with `key` and `payload` of message inside the `log.message`.

Is there any way to customize the logging config used in `org.springframework.kafka.support.LoggingProducerListener` or we should surround the kafkaTemplate.send inside a try catch so we can log our own custom logging.

```
@Component
public class CustomPublisher {

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier(KafkaProducerConfiguration.DEFAULT_PUBLISHER)
   private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

   @Autowired
   private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

   @SneakyThrows
   public void sendKafkaObjectDto(ObjectDTO message) {
      final String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(message);
      kafkaTemplate.send("topic_name", message.getKey(), json);
   }

}
```

When the `kafkaTemplate.send` failed the logger will log it like this

```
{"@timestamp":"2023-02-21T14:02:37.906+07:00","@version":"1","environment":"production","headers":{},"host":"service-prd-000112","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"log.file.directory":"logs","logger_name":"org.springframework.kafka.support.LoggingProducerListener","message":"Exception thrown when sending a message with key='keys' and payload='{\json_payload...' to topic com.ajaib.coin.data.message.coin.pair.detail.message:","message_key":null,"offset":158198,"partition":1,"service_type":"java","source_type":"kafka","stack_trace":"org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 7 record(s) for payload.message-0:120000 ms has passed since batch creation\n","thread_name":"kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1","topic":"logging_production.service"}
```

I want to customize the `"message"` so the log will not logging `key` and `payload` inside the message string. as example the "message" will be like this

```
"message":"Exception thrown when sending a message with key='keys' and payload='{\json_payload...' to topic com.ajaib.coin.data.message.coin.pair.detail.message:"
```

This is the configuration of kafkaProducer that we use

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfiguration {

    public static final String DEFAULT_PUBLISHER = "kafkaTemplate";

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String brokers;

    @Autowired
    private MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

    @Bean(name = DEFAULT_PUBLISHER)
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory(kafkaProperties));
    }

    private ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory factory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, String>(kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties());
        factory.addListener(new MicrometerProducerListener(meterRegistry));
        return factory;
    }

}
```

Can it achieved by changing the kafka producer configuration only?

Comment: This seems like a log4j / logback config, more than anything to do with Kafka. Or can you use external tooling to obfuscate log patterns

Comment: There is a static method on `KafkaUtils` to format producer and consumer records for logging.

Answer (score 0):

See `KafkaUtils.setProducerRecordFormatter()`.

```java
/**
 * Set a formatter for logging {@link ProducerRecord}s.
 * @param formatter a function to format the record as a String
 * @since 2.7.12
 */
public static void setProducerRecordFormatter(Function<ProducerRecord<?, ?>, String> formatter) {
```

Comment: is the formatter will works for Error log only, or other log level will be affected too?

Comment: what java version and kafka version that provide the `setProducerRecordFormatter` method. I use java 11 and didn't find it

Comment: As you can see from the comment, it was added in version 2.7.12; it was also included in 2.8.4; only 2.9.6 and later are currently supported as OSS; the java version doesn't matter (8 or later). Yes, in all supported versions, it is used by all logs created by the framework; if there are any that don't use it, it's a bug.